# Mac OS Expect Command for Profile Removal

Tags: bash, macos, expect

We are replacing the profile we use for our company, and we need to run a command to remove the old profiles.

```
/usr/bin/profiles -D
```

it asks for input from the user "Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? [y/n]:"

We are trying to automate this process, and have looked into the expect command but are having trouble getting it to run.

```
/usr/bin/expect -f - <<EOD

spawn /usr/bin/profiles -D 

expect "Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? [y/n]:"
send "y\n"
EOD
```

But we get this error when we try and run it.

```
 sudo /Users/gpmacarthur/Desktop/test.sh 
spawn /usr/bin/profiles -D
invalid command name "y/n"
    while executing
"y/n"
    invoked from within
"expect "Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? [y/n]:""
```

Can anyone please help us, we'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `expect` here.  You can just use the following flag:

> `-f,  auto confirm any questions`

i.e.

```
/usr/bin/profiles -fD
```

---

<sup>since I already typed up the `expect` explanation:</sup>

Square brackets are evaluated as command substitutions and also need to be escaped in regex matches.  You can use the `{}` notation to avoid this.

```
/usr/bin/expect -f - <<EOD

spawn /usr/bin/profiles -D 

expect {Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? \[y/n]:}
send "y\n"
EOD
```

Comment: Why `\r\n` for `send "y\r\n"`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tcl's `[...]` is the command substitution syntax just like `$(...)` in Bash.
2. And `[...]` is also special for glob patterns (or regular expressions).

So you should write like this:

```
/usr/bin/expect -f - << 'QUOTED-EOD'
spawn /usr/bin/profiles -D 

expect "Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? \\\[y/n]:"
send "y\n"

expect eof;  # This is required!
QUOTED-EOD
```

Or you can use Tcl's `{...}` quote style (like Bash's single quotes `'...'`):

```
expect {Are you sure you want to delete all configuration profiles? \[y/n]:}; # The `[' still needs to be escaped.
```

Or just

```
expect {\[y/n]:}
```